# Using Memcache with GAE, Java and JDO transactions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I use GAE (Java). I use JDO & transactions at the moment, I'd like to use memcache too. Right now I do:

```
Open manager
Begin transaction
Get entity from db
Change entity
Commit transaction
close manager
```

With memcache I am a bit confused, I have 2 possibilities and a question to each of them:
1:

```
Open manager
Begin transaction
getIdentifiable from memcache -> get from db if not in memcache
Change entity
Commit transaction
Put to memcache if untouched (what if it was touched in meantime and I already commited the transaction)?
Close manager
```

Or 2:

```
Open manager
Begin transaction
getIdentifiable from memcache -> get from db if not in memcache
Change entity
Put to memcache if untouched 
Commit transaction (what if transaction fails now and will be rolled back, and I've already put new value to memcache?)
Close manager
```

The questions are inside the pseudo-code. I just worry that my data will desynchronize between datastore and memcache, as I can't do the commit and putIfUntouched in the same time - if I succeed with one of them, there is still a chance I'll fail on the other one. How it should be done?

[edit]
After a while, I guess 2) is better than 1), but still, what should I do if I put the value to memcache and the transaction fails?

Comment: use memcache where ? manually calling it yourself? or JDO using it automatically?

Comment: JDO can use memcache automatically !? I thought about calling it manually, I never heard that you can make it work automatically... Could you provide some links or explain it more?

Comment: Look at the Level 2 cache in the DataNucleus docs. You can configure it to use JCache

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was so happy 7 hours ago when I found out about this feature... Unfortunately, it does not work. The cache provided by JDO causes my app to crash. I found apropriate ticket on datanucleus and commented (more people had this problem already, unfortunately, they were ignored): http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCCORE-540. I guess I'll have to implement the caching manually.

Comment: I don't see anything "ignored" on that issue. I see someone fixed something, and people after that said they had some problem but didn't show how the developers of that software could see it, so what do you expect them to do ? L2 caching using javax.cache works great for me (my app is using v4.0.x of DataNucleus though, using RDBMS)

Answer (score 1):

You can preserve the value obtained from `getIdentifiable` if any (modify a copy instead), and if you do get something then use `https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService#putIfUntouched(java.lang.Object, com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheService.IdentifiableValue, java.lang.Object, com.google.appengine.api.memcache.Expiration)` to conditionally write the modified copy back to memcache -- a compare-and-set operation.

I'm not intimately familiar with the details of the many overloads of `putIfUntouched` in the Java interface to memcache, but the concepts are similar to the simpler implementations of compare-and-set operations in the Python implementation of the interface to the service.